# L'avare: quote "when there is food for x people, there is enough food for x+y persons"

Tags: traduction, littérature

Back in school we read L'avare. At some point he invites some people for diner. But being greedy as he is, he plans to cook/order for less people than are actually invited.

I'm looking for the quote (in French) which goes something like:
"When there is food for 6 persons, there is also food for 8 persons"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Maître Jacques — *Combien serez−vous de gens à table ?*
> Harpagon — *Nous serons huit ou dix ; mais il ne faut prendre que huit ; quand il y a à manger pour huit, il y en a bien pour dix.*
> Valère — *Cela s'entend.*

Molière, *L'Avare*, 1668.

This is still a common expression:

> *Quand y'en a pour* some number, *y'en a pour* some larger number.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the expression mainly comic, then?

Comment: @LukeSawczak the expression itself isn't really comic, but its use by Molière definitely is: usually this expression is an invitation for more people to join, while here it is used as an excuse not to serve enough food.

Comment: Funny enough (yet as always seems to happen), so shortly after reading this expression here for the first time, I encountered it again in Anne Frank: "Peter asked if I'd come again one evening ... and said that where there was room for one, there was room for two."